# Downgrade from one version to a previous version?

Tags: 10.04, 10.10, ubuntu-netbook, uninstall, versions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

Is it at all possible to downgrade from one version of Ubuntu to a previous version without doing a re-install similar to the way you can upgrade.

If so, what are the required steps?

*In this specific case from Netbook Remix 10.10 to Netbook Remix 10.04*