# Ubuntu Software Center closes seconds after started?

Tags: 12.04, software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software center not opening](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185117/software-center-not-opening)

Ubuntu software center closed after 1 second after i opened it. this is what i get when i open it with terminal

```
jeggy@localhost:~$ software-center
2012-05-29 17:33:54,755 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2012-05-29 17:33:54,832 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2012-05-29 17:33:55,217 - softwarecenter.region - WARNING - failed to use geoclue: 'org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Error.notAvailable: Geoclue master client has no usable Address providers'
2012-05-29 17:33:55,696 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2012-05-29 17:33:55,891 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 176, in <module>
    app.run(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1358, in run
    self.show_available_packages(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1288, in show_available_packages
    self.view_manager.set_active_view(ViewPages.AVAILABLE)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/viewmanager.py", line 149, in set_active_view
    view_widget.init_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py", line 133, in init_view
    SoftwarePane.init_view(self)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/softwarepane.py", line 234, in init_view
    self.datadir)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/appdetailsview.py", line 886, in __init__
    self._layout_page()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/appdetailsview.py", line 1185, in _layout_page
    self.pkg_statusbar = PackageStatusBar(self)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/appdetailsview.py", line 176, in __init__
    self.progress.set_data("transparent-bg-hint", True)
AttributeError: 'ProgressBar' object has no attribute 'set_data'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

known bug, first showed in 12.10-dev, seems to now affect 12.04? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1000238

I'd suspect it should be fixed fairly soon, **if** you are affected by the above bug & can't wait  a temp workaround here. http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11945803&postcount=31

Comment: i have played with ubuntu alot, so maybe it's my own fault :P

Comment: Thanks! that workaround worked, i just found out i have 12.10 :/ don't know how :P

Comment: It also does now affect 12.04, If you are going to keep 12.10 then I'd back up anything important externally & maybe keep an eye on this subforum for issues, ect. (not many yet, likely will be some. http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=416

Comment: thanks for the tip, but do you know how i can downgrade to 12.04 again? or is it easier to format it?

Comment: A new install is usually best, though you can try - http://askubuntu.com/questions/3659/downgrade-from-one-version-to-a-previous-version